# PHP: SQL output regex problem

Tags: php, sql, regex, preg-match-all

Code

```
<?php
$sql = file_get_contents('source.sql');
$regex = '/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS|INSERT INTO|ALTER TABLE `[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+`/';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($regex, $sql, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminnotification_inbox` (
  `notification_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `severity` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_remove` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SEVERITY` (`severity`),
  KEY `IDX_IS_READ` (`is_read`),
  KEY `IDX_IS_REMOVE` (`is_remove`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_assert` (
  `assert_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `assert_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `assert_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`assert_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='ACL Asserts' AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_role` (
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tree_level` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort_order` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `role_type` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `role_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`,`sort_order`),
  KEY `tree_level` (`tree_level`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='ACL Roles' AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

INSERT INTO `admin_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators'),
(3, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Template');
```

I'm trying to understand why above the code doesn't show tables names in output,just insert and create statements  ...

Output

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [1] => CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [2] => CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [3] => INSERT INTO ) [1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) )

Answer (score 1):

It's because the  `[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+` part is only in the third part of your "or" (and you don't have any `ALTER TABLE` statements). Use

```
'/(?:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS|INSERT INTO|ALTER TABLE) `[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+`/'
```

Comment: Well, you tried to match all instances of `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, `INSERT INTO`, and `ALTER TABLE`, followed by the table name regexp at the end. However, the matching engine doesn't know that you want the table name regexp to match each of the three possibilities unless you put `()` around the first part.

Comment: Let me put it this way: your current regexp is interpreted like this: `(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS)|(INSERT INTO)|(ALTER TABLE \`[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+\`)`

Answer (score 1):

As Spiny said, the table name match is part of the third or section. To split it out you could use:

```
$regex = '/(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS|INSERT INTO|ALTER TABLE) (`[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+`)/';
```